# episerver auto-suggestion allow multiple

Tags: episerver

I am using episerver auto suggestion like this

https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Content/Properties/Property-types/Built-in-auto-suggestion-editor/

It works fine, what I want is to let the user add multiple value from the dropdown menu. Is it possible to do? I have seen the other way with the select multiple attribute, it creates checkbox and no auto suggestion is available.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such option out-of-the-box.

The `AutoSuggestSelection` and `SelectOne` attributes result in dropdowns whereas the `SelectMany` attribute results in checkboxes.

Note however that `AutoSuggestSelection` doesn't force the user to select one of the suggested values, so it differs from the other two attributes.

There are others who [wish for an equivalent attribute for *select many* scenarios](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2014/7/Built-in-auto-suggestion-editor/), but your only option currently is to create a custom editor.